# Laying out multiple high level charts together in Bokeh

Tags: python, html, plot, bokeh

How can I layout two or more Bar charts together in one html file in Bokeh ?

I can see examples for laying out figures like triangle, square from `bokeh.plotting` together over here:

http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/layout.html

But no examples for charts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're not understanding.  You take multiple plots, and add them all to a row/column/gridplot, and you're good to go.